# Using OR in regex to replace multiple matches with JS replace()

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

A few other answers to similar questions mention to simply use an | to do multiple matches, but it doesn't seem to be working in JS for me.

I have the following string: `/hi_hawaii_zip_codes_geo.min.json` and want to output `hawaii`.

The following code doesn't work: `str.replace(/_z.*|^.{0,5}/, '')` however, running `_z.*|^.{0,5}` matches fine on regexpal.com as a test, and I'm able to replace the correct matching substrings by chaining 2 `replace()`s.

Is there some special exception for regex in JS or replace that I'm overlooking?

Comment: [`/^.{0,4}|_z.*/g`](https://regexr.com/3rkcg)

Answer (score 2):

Add the *global* flag:

```
str.replace(/_z.*|^.{0,5}/g, '')
            add “g” —————-^
```

Comment: thank you! that's what I was missing, didn't realize the particularities of replace().

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the question why `replace` needs to be used at all. There are at least 2 other approaches to getting "hawaii" from the same `str`:

```
str.match(/_(.*?)_/)[1]
```

and

```
str.split('_')[1]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of split, but really wanted to work and improve my regex through this as well.